# MVC patterns with node.js with comon layout and partials

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, layout, partials

I am trying to apply mvc pattern (as in ruby) using node.js. I would like also to use **a common layout and partials**. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744798/which-nodejs-mvc-framework-currently-has-the-best-mix-of-maturity-and-ease-of-us) post and I tried Locomotivejs, but I don't know how to apply a common layout and partials with Locomotivejs. Should I use another frameworks? if I should, which one has all these features? Could you please give me some suggestion?

Comment: There is no Ruby-like node.js framework with the same level of maturity. I've been trying out Sails.js lately and find it very promising. Also partials: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views

Comment: possible duplicate of [which NodeJS MVC framework currently has the best mix of maturity and ease of use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744798/which-nodejs-mvc-framework-currently-has-the-best-mix-of-maturity-and-ease-of-us)

Comment: Spork please read my question, I've already linked the question you linked. This isn't the same question, my question isn't about MVC framework alone, but mainly about common layout and partial with node.js

Answer (score 0):

You can see what I did in order to solve that problem with locomotive.js [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/locomotive/issues/138):